# Passing $@ to kill

Tags: linux, bash

Can somebody help me explain this script I got from a book. The exercise is to write a script called `killalljobs` that kills all background jobs.

The code given for this is:

```
  kill "$@" $( jobs -p)
```

I sure I’m being really thick here.  I understand that with command substitution $( jobs –p) is the value of all background job PIDs. Also that kill command will kill these jobs if the script is run with 'killalljobs' command. I’m not sure what the `$@` is? I know it usually expands to value of arguments given when running a script for instance.

In this case does this mean the arguments that are given to the killalljobs  command? I’m not sure what arguments you would give to the killalljobs command if that is the case?

Answer (score 3):

`"$@"` is the parameters that were given to the script in the first place, meaning that calling it with something like the violent<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
killalljobs -9
```

will translate into:

```
kill -9 <pid1> <pid2> ...
```

From the `bash` manpage, slightly paraphrased:

> `$@` Expands  to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2"`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> `-9`, as pointed out in a comment, should generally be a last resort for killing processes, as it "can't be bargained with, can't be reasoned with, doesn't feel pity, or remorse, or fear, and it absolutely will not stop, ever, until the process is dead".

I was just using it as an example of passing a parameter.

Comment: Only small comment (+1 btw), perhaps one should warn not to use `-9`; since it is a bad way to terminate processes.

Comment: ... for when it absolutely, positively has to be stopped, right **NOW!** :-)

Comment: But I've added in a note as per your suggestion, thanks, @CommuSoft.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the `man`page of `kill` (`man kill`), it shows options:

> ```
> -<signal>
> -s <signal>
> --signal <signal>
>        Specify the signal to be sent.  The signal can be specified by using name or number.  The behavior of signals is explained in signal(7) manual page.
>
> -l, --list [signal]
>           List signal names.  This option has optional argument, which will convert signal number to signal name, or other way round.
>
> -L, --table
>           List signal names in a nice table.
> ```

You can thus pass these arguments to `kill`.

For instance by using `kill -9 pid`, you immediately kill the process (not recommended though). So now you can use:

```
killalljobs -9
```

etc. to specify the task better. It will thus then expand to

```
kill -9 pid1 pid2 ... pidn
```

furthermore it allows you for instance to feed additional `pid`s:

```
killalljobs -9 epid1 epid2 epid3
```

will expend to

```
kill -9 epid1 epid2 epid3 pid1 pid2 ... pid3
```

thus not only killing background jobs, but the processes with the `pid`s you gave the script yourself.

Short answer: it gives the user more freedom to determine the exact behavior of the command, and with little implementation effort.

Answer (score 0):

`$@` represents "all the parameters passed to the script."

So, the script evaluates to "kill all the jobs returned by `jobs -p`."

Comment: You failed to explain what `"$@"` is doing there. That explanation sentence is true regardless of `"$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

This example is intended to be used as a function (or in a script) which completes a particular task, yet also accepts potentially varying arguments. 
Observe:

```
#!/bin/sh 

myfunc()
{
    echo kill "$@" $(jobs -p) 
}

myfunc -l -L


myfunc -l
```